# Logical AND operator in diab 5.7 compiler returns non-bool type

Tags: c++

When the following bit of code is compiled with the diab c++ compiler (dplusplus), it generates a conversion warning on the third line. It can be resolved by casting the result of the (&&) operator to anything other than bool.

Code:

```
bool first = 1;
bool second = 1;
bool ret = (first && second); //generates compile warning
```

Error:

> warning: (etoa:1643): narrowing or signed-to-unsigned type conversion
>   found: int to unsigned char

I verified that nothing is defining bool to another type. Does this look like a compiler issue, or is there something else I might be missing that could cause this?

Comment: In C, `&&` yields a result of type `int` with the value 0 or 1. Did it do the same thing in early versions of C++? How old this this compiler? And are you sure you're invoking it as a C++ compiler, not as a C compiler? What happens if you try to add a declaration `int class;`?

Comment: My feeling is that it's a compiler issue, indeed, but it would help to confirm that you've got a C++ standard that actually has `bool`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The message implies that `bool` is (a typedef for?) `unsigned char`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: C++'s `&&` has yielded a `bool` result, and `bool` has been a distinct fundamental type, at least since the 1998 ISO C++ standard. I suspect either an outdated C++ compiler, or a compiler acting as a C compiler.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `bool first = true;` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: I did an '#ifdef bool' to check if it was defined, but it was not. Bool is being defined by the compiler. The compiler is from ~2008. That would explain a lot if it was returning a signed int. Does that imply that the bool is unsigned?

Comment: @Grant: `#ifdef bool` only tells you whether `bool` is defined *as a macro*. It could still be a typedef in some header. (That's assuming it's not a keyword, which it must be for C++ compiler that conforms to the 1998 standard or later.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Sorry, that was a typo. It is bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wind River's web site](http://www.windriver.com/products/development_suite/wind_river_compiler/) indicates that the Diab compiler can compile either C or C++.

In C, the `&&` operator yields a result of type `int`, with the value `0` or `1`. That's consistent with the warning you're seeing.

As of the 1990 ISO standard, C did not have a built-in `bool` type. It was common to define `bool` as a typedef. It appears from the message that `bool` is a typedef for `unsigned char`, probably in some header.  The 1999 ISO C standard adds a new predefined boolean type called `_Bool`; the identifier `bool` is defined in `<stdbool.h>` as a macro that expands to `_Bool`. But if `<stdbool.h>` isn't included, `bool` can be defined in some other way.

In C++, `&&` yields a result of type `bool` with the value `false` or `true`, and `bool` is a distinct fundamental type. This has been the case at least since the 1998 ISO C++ standard.

I strongly suspect you're getting this warning because you're compiling your code as C rather than as C++. A less likely possibility is that the Diab compiler doesn't fully conform to the C++ standard; it might have a way to tell it to conform more closely.

I haven't used the Diab compiler. Typically you can control the language being compiled by using a particular file extension (typically `.c` for C and `.cpp` for C++), or by using a different command, or both.

Consult the compiler's documentation to find out how to invoke it as a conforming C++ compiler.

As an experiment, before changing the way you invoke the compiler, you might try adding a declaration:

```
int class;
```

to your source file.  This is legal in C, but a syntax error in C++ (since `class` is a C++ keyword).

**UPDATE:**

The OP says he's definitely compiling as C++, not as C.  But the warning message implies that `&&` yields `int`, and that `bool` is the same type as `unsigned char`.

A warning doesn't directly indicate that the compiler is not conforming; compilers can warn about anything they like. But the content of this warning does suggest a compiler bug, or at least a compiler that doesn't conform to any C+

Any conforming C++ compiler must produce diagnostics for this program. What does your compiler do? (Please *don't* add any `#include` directives.)

```
int main() {
    class dummy { };         // Just to make sure it's C++
    bool b;
    unsigned char c;
    bool* pb = &c;           // Invalid conversion
    unsigned char* pc = &b;  // Invalid conversion
}
```

And what output do you get when you compile and execute this program?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "__cplusplus = " << __cplusplus << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It is most definitely compiling in C++. I originally found this issue within a class method. Additionally, it is invoking dplus (the c++ compiler) rather than dcc (the c compiler.)

Comment: @Grant: Interesting. Does the compiler have options that control its level of standard conformance and/or which version of the C++ standard it attempts to conform to?

Comment: @Grant, I suspect you're inadvertently including a header file that does the `typedef` of `bool` which is overriding the built-in C++ type.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `bool` is a C++ keyword; a typedef of `bool` would be a syntax error.

Comment: @KeithThompson, it *should* be a syntax error but if it isn't, that would be pretty minor as bugs go.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I disagree; failing to treat a keyword as a keyword would be a major bug.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I appreciate your detailed comments on the issue. __cplusplus is 199711. The invalid conversion lines in your code snippet throw a fatal compiler error (unsigned char* cannot be used to initialize bool* and vice versa). This is different than warnings I got before which were lint warnings.

Comment: @Grant: `lint` is not the compiler; it's a separate tool that does its own parsing and semantic analysis. And there are multiple versions of `lint`, usually not even produced by the same developers who wrote the compiler. This may be a bug in `lint`. (I wish you had mentioned in your original question that the warning is from lint.) Do you get a warning on the code in your question *from the compiler*?

Comment: The warning is generated when -Xlint option is enabled on the compiler (not a separate tool.) I did some further digging and found that, for an operation like (A && B), the compiler casts 8-bit bools up to a 32 bit integer then outputs either A or B (as a signed integer) depending on what operation is being performed. This exactly matches the behavior mentioned in your prior comments. Many thanks again for your help.